# Match strings not ending with character p

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regex to match strings containing four consecutive digits not followed by the character `p`.

This is what I have: `\d\d\d\d`

But I don't want the regex to match strings such as `1111p`. How can I improve my regex?

Comment: This is simple one if you know `lookaround` assertions.

Comment: take a look at the use of the carat `^` character

Answer (score 2):

You need to `lookahead` negative for presence of `p` i.e absence of `p`

**Regex:** `\d{4}(?!p)`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lA5aO3/1)

Answer (score 0):

`/(\d{4})(?!p)/` will capture all groups of four digits that aren’t followed by the character `p`. The `{}` is a [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) that allows you to specify a minimum, maximum, or exact number of repetitions and the `(?!)` is a special non-capturing group called a [“negative lookahead”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).